# Filter out all full stops from a string, but keep decimal points in numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove all full stops from a string, but keep the decimal points within numbers, for example:

`'This 12.6 decimal point should stay. But full stops should go.'`


`--> 'This 12.6 decimal point should stay But full stops should go'`

I think Regex would be the correct way with a replace, but can't seem to work out a correct pattern. 
Cheers for any help.

Comment: ideally simplest way to do this would be to check for a number (0-9) before and after the *.* and let it remain and remove all the other *.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With negative lookahead assertion `(?!...)`:

```js
var str = 'This 12.6 decimal point should stay. But full stops should go.',
    result = str.replace(/\.(?!\d)/g, '');

console.log(result);
```

---

`\.(?!\d)` - ensures that `.` is not followed by a digit

Answer (score 0):

You could take a positive lookahead for a whitespace or end of string and replace only the found dot with an empty string.

```js
var string = 'This 12.6 decimal point should stay. But full stops should go.'

string = string.replace(/\.(?=\s|$)/g, '');

console.log(string);
```